# Javah gives error while using it in JNI

Tags: java

I'm very new to JNI, and trying to write a HelloWorld program using the tutorial given [here](http://www.inonit.com/cygwin/jni/helloWorld/header.html) 
and on giving the command as

`javah HelloWorld` or `javah -classpath <classpath> HelloWorld` for different  values

for eg. javah -classpath /home/my_myfolder -o HelloWorld.h example.jni.HelloWorld

but I am getting

```
 error: cannot access HelloWorld
 class file for HelloWorld not found
 javadoc : error -Class HelloWorld not found
 Error : No classes were specified on the command line.
```

I have already tried all the answers listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986262/javah-error-while-using-it-in-jni) but none have worked for me.
If you could be a little specific with what to specify as my classpath, I'd be grateful. Assume my code `HelloWorld.java` is in `/home/my_folder`, as is the `HelloWorld.class` file.

UPDATE -- Okay, so the problem was solved, and it wasn't the classpath at all, but the example program given in the link that I used was itself faulty.

There is an extra `HelloWorld obj = new HelloWorld();` required in the sample code., in the `main()` function.

Comment: What is the exact command you're giving to get that message?

Comment: I've tried `javah HelloWorld` and different combinations of some classpaths to `javah -classpath <classpath> HelloWorld`

Comment: `javah -classpath /home/my_folder -o HelloWorld.h example.jni.HelloWorld`?

Comment: Consider using JNA instead of JNI; it's less hassle. https://github.com/twall/jna

Comment: Joachim Isaksson -- I have used the same, but it still gives the same error. I'll try using JNA

Comment: Did you compile the java class before running `javah`?

Answer (score 0):

The argument to javah is a complete class name including the package name, same as for the java command. See the [tool documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javah.html).

Comment: You should really provide examples, or at least a link to the tool docs.

Comment: If the downvote is supposed to convey that the answer isn't useful as it stands, I disagree, and I also disagree with @NathanielFord that an example is needed of something as some as a complete class name.

Comment: upvote, because EJP is correct and google is a tool to use in such a case.

Comment: @NathanielFord It is certainly not imprecise in any way. It is a precise and concise statement of the facts, and the imputation of laziness is both irrelevant and offensive.

Comment: I apologize if I have given offense; I am not implying you're lazy, but that the answer is. I think this is relevant because it speaks directly to the quality of answers on S.O. You are of a different opinion, and that's fine; that is why the vote mechanism is in place.