# Javah error, cannot find class file

Tags: java-native-interface

When I tried to use javah to generate header files, I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find class file for 'HelloWorld'.
```

Here is my External tools configuration.

Location: ${system_path:javah}

Working Directory: ${workspace_loc:/JniJava/bin/sonyraj}

Arguments: -jni HelloWorld

Comment: try from the commnnd line/ terminal. maybe javah needs the full path to it? and try without packages?

Comment: this has some results that look good https://www.google.com/search?q=javah+tutorial

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986262/javah-error-while-using-it-in-jni

Comment: @tgkprog thanks for your reply, tried in the command line too,but i am getting the same error

Comment: Got it! without packages it worked! thanks again @tgkprog :-)

Comment: welcome entered as an answer so you can mark it as accepted :) see [FAQ] for why ...

Comment: please accept my answer by clicking the tick near it see [faq] on why that is a god idea to accept answered questions on stackoverflow :) @sony

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try from the commnnd line/ terminal. maybe javah needs the full path to it? And without packages.

Or fully qualified package name as noted here [Javah error while using it in JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986262/javah-error-while-using-it-in-jni)

> `javah -jni com.example.JavaHowTo`

where `com.example` is your package.

You also need to run javah from the directory containing `com/example/JavaHowTo.class`

e.g. if your structure is

```
/home/user/project/Iot/com/example/JavaHotTo.class
```

run javah from

```
/home/user/project/Iot
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, try to put your .class files in a folder with the same name as the package name. Then run "javah packagename.ClassName". Hope it works for you too.