# Ubuntu 14.04, Eclipse, Javah command cant find .class file

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, javah

Javah command will not work, ive tried numerous ones and each time it just returns java.class cannot be found these are the commands i've attempted:

javah -jni com.Lewis.NativeLib. at the /Home/Workspace/NDKdemo/bin/classes directorty.

javah -jni NativeLib. at /Home/Workspace/NDKdemo/bin/classes/com/Lewis.

Please do not point me to another answer that only contains the above commands I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run it without the dot at the end of the command?

```
javah -jni com.Lewis.NativeLib
```

Like as explained at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986262/javah-error-while-using-it-in-jni):

```
javah -jni com.example.JavaHowTo
```

where com.example is your package.